# Metronic generated layout don't see css styles

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, metronic

i am trying to generate metronic layout with layout builder, but when I try to open index.html I just see this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffc7Q.jpg)

It seems to me like it can't see css styles

When I open just html demo, it works well.. I did by tutorial, I generated assets by gulp, so I don't know what to do now..
Btw. using Mac

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the generated assets folder from the downloaded zip file.

Copy from `/html/demo1/dist/assets` into exported layout builder folder.

You don't need to rebuild the assets using `gulp` if you don't modify any assets file from the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Metronic is a paid UI kit, the css, js and main theme file need to be downloaded in the member portal.

https://devs.keenthemes.com/metronic

The layout builder just gives you the html layout, but is no use without the main theme files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34325831)